# Printing data in ListView instead of toast

Tags: android, android-listview

I have problem i am getting my data from one activity. i want to print that using a list view. How can i do it.?

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> fruitSelection = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("fruits");

    if (fruitSelection != null) {
        // use a toast to display selected fruits
        if (fruitSelection.size() > 0) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Your selection of fruits\n\n");
            for (String s : fruitSelection) {
                sb.append("* ").append(s).append("\n");
            }
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, sb.toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();}
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Try [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=android+listactivity+example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=android+listview+example+using+arraylist&oq=android+listview+example+using+arraylist&gs_l=serp.3..0i22.166523.171334.0.172204.31.18.0.0.0.3.1908.9868.3-1j3j3j3j1j1.12.0.les%3Bernk_fspiked..0.0...1c.0eOG--nVawE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=ba095659e45f8125&biw=1440&bih=785)

Answer (score 3):

Create a class that extends [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) and use .setAdapter() on your ListView.

See this for more info : 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're viewing the "fruit" data in another activity, set the second Activity to extend `ListActivity` and set the `Adapter` on the ListActivity's ListView to access the fruit array.

```
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_view_item, fruitSelection);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> fruitSelection = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("fruits");

ListView  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, fruitSelection);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);



            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```